# ATR maType, how to use it

Tags: r, xts

I'm using the ATR function in the TTR package. The docs says that you can specify a moving average type. I want to know what this means, for example does this mean that my ATR values will be smoothed by the maType I choose to use ?

If so what would be the correct syntax for using an maType and specifying the maType period ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The docs says that you can specify a moving average type. I want to know what this means...

It means you can specify a moving average type other than the default. I'm not sure what else it could mean...

> ...does this mean that my ATR values will be smoothed by the maType I choose to use?

No. It means that the true range values will be smoothed by the `maType` you use, which creates an Average True Range (ATR).

> If so what would be the correct syntax for using an maType and specifying the maType period?

The same as you specify any other function argument: `ATR(x, maType=EMA)`. Regarding how to set the period, I quote the documentation, "n: Number of periods for moving average.".

---

Suggestions for how to improve the documentation is welcome.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for answering. To be honest I find that the documentation for R is pretty difficult to decipher sometimes, but short of providing a use case example for every option (which I know is unrealistic) I'm not sure there is an easy way to improve.